# Header in RecyclerView with different layouts

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have RecyclerView with Banner as a header view, I want it to have different layouts in landscape and portrait modes, how can I achieve this?
Putting different layouts in "layout" and "layout-land" folders does not work, and onCreateViewHolder and onBindViewHolder are not called on orientation change.

Comment: In other words, how can I update first ViewHolder from onConfigurationChanged callback

Comment: Is your recyclerview in an activity? How are you populating the adapter and restoring the state of your fragment/activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That solved my problem:

```
@Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);

        if (mAdapter != null && mAdapter.getItemCount() > 0) {
            mAdapter.notifyItemChanged(0);
        }
    }
```